# How to get rid of performance suggestion on Samsung Devices

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4

How do I get rid of this really annoying performance suggestion that pops up probably 50 times a day?

[image: Screenshot of Performance-Suggestion on a Samsung device]

Comment: I've never seen a popup like that on any of my LP devices. What's bringing this notification(?) up? Maybe you just get rid of that?

Comment: how can I find that out? coz that icon is one I've never seen before and I thought it was CM security but even after removing that it still persists @Izzy

Comment: It *should* be long-pressing the notification to pop up a context menu or going straight to the app-details of the app behind it. On my LP devices that first "silences" the notification, but a.o. shows an ⓘ icon on it. Tapping that goes to the notification settings for the app, showing the app's name in the title bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android version 5.0 or above you can always block notification of a app. 
Long click on the notification you want to block, you will get a icon 'i' at right corner
Click on it and then select block all and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it was the Samsung Smart Manager that was sending these suggestions. I had to root the device using [Kingo Root](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-root-galaxy-s4.htm) and then remove Smart Manager using [Kingo Super Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kingouser.com). 

[This link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/587792-app-causing-your-device-run-slowly-hundreds-times-day.html) also has a similar problem.

Comment: If you are using Android version 5.0 or above you can always block notification of a app. Long click on the notification you will get a icon 'i' at right corner click on it and then select block all and we are done.

Comment: that I didnt know of...